# How to calculate total within sum of squares and between sum of squares for ward hierarchical clustering?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

How would I calculate the total within sum of squares and between sum of squares for the ward clustering below? I have looked at several resources online and have not been successful. I came across the css package but it is not compatible with my version of R which is 4.1.2

```
   hier_ward <- hclust(distance_matrix, method='ward')
    cut_ward <- cutree(hier_ward, k=6)
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the `iris` data set which is included in R. Load the data and then compute the cluster analysis excluding column 5 which contains character data.

```
data(iris)
iris.dist <- dist(iris[, -5])
iris.hclust <- hclust(iris.dist, method="ward.D")
iris.6 <- cutree(iris.hclust, k=6)
```

The total sum of squares can be calculated using the `scale()` function to center the values on the mean:

```
TSS <- sum(colSums(scale(iris[, -5], scale=FALSE)^2))
TSS
# [1] 681.3706
```

Then we split the data into the clusters defined by `iris.6` and compute the sums of squares for each group:

```
groups <- split(iris[, -5], iris.6)
WSS <- sapply(groups, function(x) sum(colSums(scale(x, scale=FALSE)^2)))
WSS
#         1         2         3         4         5         6 
#  5.814375  2.331667 12.708947  8.942308  5.567500  4.655000 
# sum(WSS)
# [1] 40.0198
```